# How to get indexes of specific array elements in Apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Using apps script I have:

```
var conversation = [R: test1 ,  R: test3 ,  tx ,  I sent ]
```

I wanted to get a list of the INDEXES of elements containing 'R:' so I tried

```
var replies = conversation.map(function(message) { 
    message.indexOf('R:')!== -1 && return conversation.indexOf(message);

});
```

But now I can't save the function and I'm getting a syntax error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reduce and keep pushing indexes where you find `R:`

```js
var conversations = ['R: test1' ,'R: test3','tx','I sent' ]

var replies = conversations.reduce(function(op,message,index) {
    if(message.indexOf('R:')!== -1) {
      op.push(index)
    }
    return op
},[]);  

console.log(replies)
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. You can't do this with just `map`.
2. You have your `return` in the wrong place, which is the cause of the syntax error.

To do it in a single pass, the simplest thing is to use `forEach` and `push` (since Apps script doesn't support `for-of`):

```
var replies = [];
conversation.forEach(function(message, index) {
    if (message.indexOf("R:") !== -1) {
        replies.push(index);
    }
});
```

but you could do it in two passes with `map` and `filter`:

```
var replies = conversation
    .map(function(message, index) {
        return message.indexOf("R:") !== -1 ? index : -1;
    })
    .filter(function(index) {
        return index !== -1;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you - I've decided to go with reduce since I've never used it before. Thanks for the explanations.

Comment: @user61629 - No worries! Just FYI, using `reduce` when the accumulator never changes (as in this case, it's always the same array) is sometimes considered poor style. It's very common, though. Not arguing that you should change your accepted answer (please don't), just be aware that the primary use case for `reduce` is things like sums and such where the accumulator constantly changes. Ex: `[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(s, n) { return s + n; }, 0);`